# List comprehensions vs higher ordered functions

Tags: erlang, list-comprehension, higher-order-functions

Which of the following code snippets is preferred? And why?

```
check_number(X) ->                                                                    
    case lists:filter(fun(Y) -> check_num(Y) end, lists:seq(1,X)) of                  
        [] -> empty;            
        List -> io:format("~w~n", [List]) 
    end.
```

Or

```
check_number(X) ->
    io:format("~w~n", [[N || N <- lists:seq(1,X), check_num(N)]]).
```

Assuming that check_num(N) is a predicate.

Comment: I think, it's Erlang code! Please use an appropriate tag.

Comment: what does check_num function do?

Comment: Yes it is Erlang code, and check_num is a predicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your second function is not equal to the first. You could write your first function that would be equal to the second like that:

```
check_number(X) ->
    io:format("~w~n", [lists:filter(fun check_num/1, lists:seq(1,X))]).
```

As you can see it doesn't look much bigger. And which one to use depends exclusively on your and your colleagues' sense of beauty.

Answer (score 2):

What exactly is your function `check_number/1` supposed to do? The first one *returns* `empty` if there are no integers which satisfy `check_num/1` while if there are such integers it *prints* the list of them and *returns* `ok` (the return value of `io:format`). While the second one always *prints* the list, even if it is empty, and *returns* `ok`.

Note that printing a value and returning are two completely different things. Hence my question on what your function is supposed to do.

Which alternative is purely a match of choice here and you can choose the one which you feels looks better. List comprehensions often provide a concise way of expressing maps and filters.

Comment: Hi Robert, the check_num/1 is supposed to find such integers: "48 is an interesting number. If you add 1, you get 49, a perfect square. If you divide it by 2 and then add 1, you get 25, another perfect square. What is the next integer with this property?". My question was intended for mainly to clarify the difference between HOF and List comprehensions, which is preferred to use and why.

Comment: OK, gotcha. I was just a little worried as many coming from a non-functional background do confuse printing a value with returning a value. Especially as the shell prints the return values which even more tends to hide the difference.